# Why is the error "Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset" when encoding JSON using case classes?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-encoders

I've written spark job:

```
object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val ctx = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import ctx.implicits._

    case class Person(age: Long, city: String, id: String, lname: String, name: String, sex: String)
    case class Person2(name: String, age: Long, city: String)

    val persons = ctx.read.json("/tmp/persons.json").as[Person]
    persons.printSchema()
  }
}
```

In IDE when I run the main function, 2 error occurs:

```
Error:(15, 67) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing sqlContext.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
    val persons = ctx.read.json("/tmp/persons.json").as[Person]
                                                                  ^

Error:(15, 67) not enough arguments for method as: (implicit evidence$1: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[Person])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Person].
Unspecified value parameter evidence$1.
    val persons = ctx.read.json("/tmp/persons.json").as[Person]
                                                                  ^
```

but in Spark Shell I can run this job without any error. what is the problem?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The error message says that the `Encoder` is not able to take the `Person` case class.

```
Error:(15, 67) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing sqlContext.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
```

Move the declaration of the case class outside the scope of `SimpleApp`.

Comment: Why does scoping make any difference here? I am getting that error while using the REPL.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the why the scope of case class is making the difference if you can point me to any resource that I can read and understand it will be of great help.  Pretty new with scala implicit :( @jacek-laskowski

Comment: I don't think I'm capable of explaining why the solution works the way it does. I vaguely remember that it has nothing to do with implicits which are simply a mechanism to plug a code and think the code itself is the root cause.

Answer (score 4):

You have the same error if you add `sqlContext.implicits._` and `spark.implicits._` in `SimpleApp` (the order doesn't matter).

Removing one or the other will be the solution:

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .getOrCreate()

val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
import sqlContext.implicits._ //sqlContext OR spark implicits
//import spark.implicits._ //sqlContext OR spark implicits

case class Person(age: Long, city: String)
val persons = ctx.read.json("/tmp/persons.json").as[Person]
```

Tested with **Spark 2.1.0**

The funny thing is if you add the same object implicits twice you will not have problems.

Answer (score 3):

@Milad Khajavi

Define Person case classes outside object SimpleApp.
Also, add import sqlContext.implicits._ inside main() function.