# Why is "Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset" when creating a dataset of custom case class?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-encoders

Spark 2.0 (final) with Scala 2.11.8. The following super simple code yields the compilation error `Error:(17, 45) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

case class SimpleTuple(id: Int, desc: String)

object DatasetTest {
  val dataList = List(
    SimpleTuple(5, "abc"),
    SimpleTuple(6, "bcd")
  )

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.
      master("local")
      .appName("example")
      .getOrCreate()

    val dataset = sparkSession.createDataset(dataList)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Spark `Datasets` require `Encoders` for data type which is about to be stored. For common types (atomics, product types) there is a number of predefined encoders available but you have to import these first from [`SparkSession.implicits`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$implicits$) to make it work:

```
val sparkSession: SparkSession = ???
import sparkSession.implicits._
val dataset = sparkSession.createDataset(dataList)
```

Alternatively you can provide directly an explicit

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}

val dataset = sparkSession.createDataset(dataList)(Encoders.product[SimpleTuple])
```

or implicit

```
implicit val enc: Encoder[SimpleTuple] = Encoders.product[SimpleTuple]
val dataset = sparkSession.createDataset(dataList)
```

`Encoder` for the stored type.

Note that `Encoders` also provide a number of predefined `Encoders` for atomic types, and `Encoders` for complex ones, can derived with [`ExpressionEncoder`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bapache-spark%5D+ExpressionEncoder).

Further reading:

- For custom objects which are not covered by built-in encoders see [How to store custom objects in Dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36648128/1560062)
- For `Row` objects you have to provide `Encoder` explicitly as shown in [Encoder error while trying to map dataframe row to updated row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39433419/1560062)
- For debug cases, case class must be defined outside of the Main https://stackoverflow.com/a/34715827/3535853

Comment: Maybe this is obvious to scala developers, but i know more spark then scala... Why is using `= ???` okay, and or better then actually declaring it?

Comment: @DanCiborowski-MSFT `???` is [NotImplementedError](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/NotImplementedError.html) - in other words fill the blank according to your requirements.

Answer (score 70):

For other users (yours is correct), note that you it's also important that the `case class` is defined outside of the `object` scope. So:

Fails:

```
object DatasetTest {
  case class SimpleTuple(id: Int, desc: String)

  val dataList = List(
    SimpleTuple(5, "abc"),
    SimpleTuple(6, "bcd")
  )

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
      .master("local")
      .appName("example")
      .getOrCreate()
    val dataset = sparkSession.createDataset(dataList)
  }
}
```

Add the implicits, still fails with the same error:

```
object DatasetTest {
  case class SimpleTuple(id: Int, desc: String)

  val dataList = List(
    SimpleTuple(5, "abc"),
    SimpleTuple(6, "bcd")
  )

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
      .master("local")
      .appName("example")
      .getOrCreate()

    import sparkSession.implicits._
    val dataset = sparkSession.createDataset(dataList)
  }
}
```

Works:

```
case class SimpleTuple(id: Int, desc: String)

object DatasetTest {   
  val dataList = List(
    SimpleTuple(5, "abc"),
    SimpleTuple(6, "bcd")
  )

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
      .master("local")
      .appName("example")
      .getOrCreate()

    import sparkSession.implicits._
    val dataset = sparkSession.createDataset(dataList)
  }
}
```

Here's the relevant bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13540, so hopefully it will be fixed in the next release of Spark 2.

(Edit: Looks like that bugfix is actually in Spark 2.0.0... So I'm not sure why this still fails).

Comment: This still seems to be an issue in Spark 2.4

Comment: Worked for me though!

Comment: very important `case class is defined outside of the object scope.` Thanks!

Comment: For spark 3.0.1, it still fails and case class needs to be outside the object scope.

Comment: For those having this error using Zeppelin, declaring the case classes in one paragraph and creating the Dataset in the next one it will solve the issue. I had the error when I made both calls in the same paragraph.

Answer (score -1):

I'd clarify with an answer to my own question, that if the goal is to define a simple literal SparkData frame, rather than use Scala tuples and implicit conversion, the simpler route is to use the Spark API directly like this:

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

  val simpleSchema = StructType(
    StructField("a", StringType) ::
    StructField("b", IntegerType) ::
    StructField("c", IntegerType) ::
    StructField("d", IntegerType) ::
    StructField("e", IntegerType) :: Nil)

  val data = List(
    Row("001", 1, 0, 3, 4),
    Row("001", 3, 4, 1, 7),
    Row("001", null, 0, 6, 4),
    Row("003", 1, 4, 5, 7),
    Row("003", 5, 4, null, 2),
    Row("003", 4, null, 9, 2),
    Row("003", 2, 3, 0, 1)
  )

  val df = spark.createDataFrame(data.asJava, simpleSchema)
```

Comment: The goat was to create a dataset, not a dataframe.