# Add an empty Column in between while selecting columns in a Dataframe (Spark)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to add an empty column in between two columns in a dataframe select statement.

Using the `withColumn` function, I'm able to append only as an end column, but I need the empty column in the middle (3rd column & 6th column) as shown below.

```
val product1 = product.select("_c1","_c2"," ","_c4", "_c5", "_c5", " ", "c6")
```

I tried using `withColumn` in the middle of the `select` statement as shown below which gives the error:

```
val product1 = product.select("_c1","_c2",product.withColumn("NewCol",lit(None).cast("string")),"_c4", "_c5", "_c5", " ", "c6")

>error: overloaded method value select with alternatives:
  (col: String,cols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, String)
```

Please let me know if any suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For selecting columns in dataframes, it is possible to use either strings (column names) or the columns (of [`Column`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html) type) as input. From the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@select(col:String,cols:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame):

> ```
> def select(col: String, cols: String*): DataFrame  
> Selects a set of columns.
> ```

> ```
> def select(cols: Column*): DataFrame  
> Selects a set of column based expressions.
> ```

However, these can not be mixed. In this case, use the `select` with `Column` type. To get the column of a specific name, use the `col` function or `$` (after [importing spark implicits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39151189/importing-spark-implicits-in-scala)).

```
val spark = SparkSession()....
import spark.implicits._

val product1 = product.select($"_c1", $"_c2", lit(" ").as("newCol1"), $"_c4", $"_c5", $"_c5", lit(" ").as("newCol2"), $"c6")
```