# How to perform Unit testing on PySpark Structured Streaming?

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming

I'm using PySpark Structured Streaming with Kafka as a reader stream. For the sake of unit testing, I would like to replace Kafka reader stream with a mock. How can I do this?

The following question is equivalent to mine but I use Python (PySpark) instead of Scala. And I couldn't find MemoryStream in PySpark.

[How to perform Unit testing on Spark Structured Streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56894068/how-to-perform-unit-testing-on-spark-structured-streaming)

Comment: I don't think you need to directly use `MemoryStream`, you can do `df.writeStream.queryName("aggregates").outputMode("complete") .format("memory").start()` in python.
See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: @RayanRal thanks for your reply. AFAIU, your snippet allows me to mock the writeStream (output) of the streaming while I'm trying to mock the readerStream (input).

Comment: @Ronen491 haven't you found an answer yet?

Comment: @VB_ I ended up with creating a json file for every message I would stream through kafka and used something like:
`df = spark.readStream.format('json').option('maxFilesPerTrigger', 1).schema(StructType([StructField('key', StringType(), True), StructField('value', StringType(), True)])).load('*.json')
`