# Spark Memory Streams keeps on running?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a simple memory stream query but it keeps on running.

This is my write query

```
  val imStream = new MemoryStream[SomeData](1, spark.sqlContext)

  val mV = imStream.toDS()
    .groupByKey(...)
    .flatMapGroupsWithState......//returning the values without any logic

  val sQ = mV
    .writeStream
    .format("memory")
    .queryName(queryName)
    .option("checkpointLocation", "src/checkpoint")
    .start


  val currentOffset: Offset = imStream.addData(dataList)
  val nextOffset = imStream.addData(Seq(.....))

  sQ.processAllAvailable()
  imStream.commit(currentOffset.asInstanceOf[LongOffset])
  imStream.commit(nextOffset.asInstanceOf[LongOffset])

  sQ.awaitTermination(5000L)
```

I am using it for testigng, but it keeps on running. I also tried `sQ.stop()` but it was not making any difference ?

Am I missing something regarding to stop the memory streams?

[Also  it seems to be working without flatMapGroupsWithState to be fine]

Comment: How are you terminating the query?

Comment: Hi @mike, I was terminating using `sQ.awaitTermination(5000L)`

Comment: and also if `sQ.processAllAvailable()` is commented, then       `spark.table(queryName).show(truncate = false)` returns nothing applied after `awaitTermination(20000L)`

Comment: I'm curious how you check that _"but it keeps on running."_?

Comment: can you try to phrase what you are actually trying to achieve? It is not clear from looking at the code. Also, a reproducable minimal example usually helps best to help you.