# Spark unable to find encoder(case class) although providing it

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Trying to figure out why getting an error on encoders, any insight would be helpful!

> ERROR  Unable to find encoder for type SolrNewsDocument, An implicit Encoder[SolrNewsDocument] is needed to store `

Clearly I have imported `spark.implicits._`. I have also have provided an encoder as a case class.

```
def ingestDocsToSolr(newsItemDF: DataFrame) = {
  case class SolrNewsDocument(
                             title: String,
                             body: String,
                             publication: String,
                             date: String,
                             byline: String,
                             length: String
                           )
  import spark.implicits._
  val solrDocs = newsItemDF.as[SolrNewsDocument].map { doc =>
    val solrDoc = new SolrInputDocument
    solrDoc.setField("title", doc.title.toString)
    solrDoc.setField("body", doc.body)
    solrDoc.setField("publication", doc.publication)
    solrDoc.setField("date", doc.date)
    solrDoc.setField("byline", doc.byline)
    solrDoc.setField("length", doc.length)

    solrDoc
  }

  // can be used for stream SolrSupport.
  SolrSupport.indexDocs("localhost:2181", "collection", 10, solrDocs.rdd);
  val solrServer = SolrSupport.getCachedCloudClient("localhost:2181")
  solrServer.setDefaultCollection("collection")
  solrServer.commit(false, false)
}
```

Comment: Try moving the case class to outside the method.

Comment: i had even trying to put it at the top of the class @Shaido

Comment: outside the class and inside above all the methods

Comment: I see. Can you try to minimize the example a bit, I'm not sure if the usage of `SolrInputDocument` results in any problems. Is it possible to simply do `newsItemDF.as[SolrNewsDocument].count()`?

Comment: @Shaido unfortunately, that exisited before that also. i also tried to verify the above same problem

Comment: Maybe some of the answers to this previous question can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664972/why-is-unable-to-find-encoder-for-type-stored-in-a-dataset-when-creating-a-dat The problem with where the case class is defined is illustrated in the second answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Check this one.-Move case class declaration before function declaration.
//Encoder is created once case class statement is executed by compiler. Then only compiler will be able to use encoder inside function deceleration.


import spark.implicits._

case class SolrNewsDocument(title: String,body: String,publication: String,date: String,byline: String,length: String)


def ingestDocsToSolr(newsItemDF:DataFrame) = {
val solrDocs = newsItemDF.as[SolrNewsDocument]}
```

Answer (score 0):

i got this error trying to iterate over a text file, and in my case, as of spark 2.4.x the issue was that i had to cast it to an RDD first (that used to be implicit)

```
textFile
  .rdd
  .flatMap(line=>line.split(" "))
```

[Migrating our Scala codebase to Spark 2](https://www.thumbtack.com/engineering/migrating-scala-codebase-spark-2/)