# Convert Array[Row] which has List of Lists to Dataframe in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Scala in Spark.

I have a input dataframe with one column.

Each element in the dataframe is List of Lists which I need to convert to Dataframe.

```
def functionName(x: DataFrame){
   //CODE TO DO ON DATAFRAME
}

> inputdf.show()

+------------------------+
|                 col    |
+------------------------+
| [[a, b, c], [d, e, f]] |
| [[g, h, i], [j, k, l]] |
| [[m, n, o], [p, q, r]] |
| [[s, t, u], [v, w, x]] |
+------------------------+
```

To convert each row to a dataframe I have used:

```
> inputdf.rdd.map(row => functionName(row.toDF()))

> inputdf.rdd.map(row => functionName(sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(row))))

> inputdf.rdd.map(row => functionName(sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(Seq(row)))))
```

Have tried most of the methods suggested on stackoverflow but none of them. Can some suggest me how to convert each row in the `inputdf` using `map` function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert scala list to DataFrame or DataSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397652/convert-scala-list-to-dataframe-or-dataset)

Comment: Hi @Pavel, I have tried the solution for the other question. But it is not the same question. Thanks for suggestion anyway.