# How to implement a trait with a generic case class that creates a dataset in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, apache-spark-sql, traits, case-class

I want to create a Scala trait that should be implemented with a case class T. The trait is simply to load data and transform it into a Spark Dataset of type T. I got the error that no encoder can be stored, which I think is because Scala does not know that T should be a case class. How can I tell the compiler that? I've seen somewhere that I should mention Product, but there is no such class defined.. Feel free to suggest other ways to do this!

I have the following code but it is not compiling with the error: 42: error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing sqlContext.implicits._
[INFO]       .as[T]

I'm using Spark 1.6.1

Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SQLContext}    

/**
      * A trait that moves data on Hadoop with Spark based on the location and the granularity of the data.
      */
    trait Agent[T] {
      /**
        * Load a Dataframe from the location and convert into a Dataset
        * @return Dataset[T]
        */
      protected def load(): Dataset[T] = {
        // Read in the data
        SparkContextKeeper.sqlContext.read
          .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
          .load("/myfolder/" + location + "/2016/10/01/")
          .as[T]
      }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715611/why-is-the-error-unable-to-find-encoder-for-type-stored-in-a-dataset-when-enco and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664972/why-is-unable-to-find-encoder-for-type-stored-in-a-dataset-when-creating-a-dat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is missing 3 things:

- Indeed, you must let compiler know that T is subclass of `Product` (the superclass of all Scala case classes and Tuples)
- Compiler would also require the `TypeTag` and `ClassTag` of the actual case class. This is used implicitly by Spark to overcome type erasure
- import of `sqlContext.implicits._`

Unfortunately, you can't add type parameters with *context bounds* in a *trait*, so the simplest workaround would be to use an `abstract class` instead:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

abstract class Agent[T <: Product : ClassTag : TypeTag] {
  protected def load(): Dataset[T] = { 
    val sqlContext: SQLContext = SparkContextKeeper.sqlContext
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    sqlContext.read.// same... 
  }
}
```

Obviously, this isn't equivalent to using a trait, and might suggest that this design isn't the best fit for the job. Another alternative is placing `load` in an *object* and moving the type parameter to the method:

```
object Agent {
  protected def load[T <: Product : ClassTag : TypeTag](): Dataset[T] = {
    // same...
  }
}
```

Which one is preferable is mostly up to where and how you're going to call `load` and what you're planning to do with the result.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, useful comment also on the design! I already tried your first and third remark, but the second one I needed to do the trick :)
Btw, I think an abstract class is fine too as I will be inheriting Agent for every dataset I'm creating..

Comment: import reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag ? from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285560/scala-compiler-says-no-typetag-available-for-t-in-method-using-generics

Answer (score 0):

You need to take two actions :

1. Add `import sparkSession.implicits._` in your imports
2. Make your trait `trait Agent[T <: Product]`