# Scala compiler says "No TypeTag available for T" in method using generics

Tags: scala, generics, methods, types

The following code is not compiling:

```
override def read[T <: Product](collection : String): Dataset[T] = {
  val mongoDbRdd = MongoSpark.load(sparkSession.sparkContext,MongoDBConfiguration.toReadConfig(collection))
  mongoDbRdd.toDS[T]
}
```

This is "toDS" definition:

```
def toDS[T <: Product: TypeTag: NotNothing](): Dataset[T] = mongoSpark.toDS[T]()
```

Compiler says:

```
Error:(11, 20) No TypeTag available for T
    mongoDbRdd.toDS[T]

Error:(11, 20) not enough arguments for method toDS: (implicit evidence$3: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T], implicit evidence$4: com.mongodb.spark.NotNothing[T])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T].
Unspecified value parameters evidence$3, evidence$4.
    mongoDbRdd.toDS[T]
```

Line 11 is `mongoDbRdd.toDS[T]`

I really don't know what's going on with Scala Generics and the compiler is not very specific, any idea?

Comment: Where is `Product` declared?

Comment: Its from Scala (package scala)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the type constraints on `T` that `toDS` requires:

```scala
// The ':' constraint is a type class constraint.
def toDS[T <: Product: TypeTag: NotNothing](): Dataset[T] =
  mongoSpark.toDS[T]()

// The below is exactly the same as the above, although with user-defined
// names for the implicit parameters.
// All a type class does is append implicit parameters to your function.
def toDS[T <: Product]()(implicit typeTag: TypeTag[T], notNothing: NotNothing[T]) =
  mongoSpark.toDS[T]()
```

You'll notice that's what your compiler error shows - with the names expanded to `evidence$3` and `evidence$4`.

If you want your method to compile, simply add the same type classes:

```
override def read[T <: Product: TypeTag: NotNothing](
    collection : String): Dataset[T] = { /* impl */ }
```

Comment: I have already tried that, but the errors are even worse:

Error:(11, 24) javassist.bytecode.stackmap.TypeTag does not take type parameters
  def read[T <: Product: TypeTag: NotNothing](collection : String): Dataset[T] = {
Error:(13, 20) No TypeTag available for T
    mongoDbRdd.toDS[T]
Error:(13, 20) not enough arguments for method toDS: (implicit evidence$3: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T], implicit evidence$4: com.mongodb.spark.NotNothing[T])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T].
Unspecified value parameters evidence$3, evidence$4.
    mongoDbRdd.toDS[T]

Comment: If you look at the error message closely, you'll see that you have the wrong `TypeTag` class in scope (`javassist.bytecode.stackmap.TypeTag`). Make sure you're importing `reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag`.

Comment: It should be javassist.bytecode.stackmap.TypeTag as @jkinkead mentioned