# Unable to find encoder for type stored in Dataset when attempting to perform flatMap on a DataFrame in Spark 2.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I keep getting the following compile time error:

```
Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  
Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) 
are supported by importing spark.implicits._  
Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
```

I've just upgraded from Spark v1.6 to v2.0.2, and a whole bunch of code using `DataFrame` are complaining about this error. The code where it is complaining looks like the following.

```
def doSomething(data: DataFrame): Unit = {
 data.flatMap(row => {
  ...
 })
 .reduceByKey(_ + _)
 .sortByKey(ascending = false)
}
```

Previous SO posts suggest to

- [pull out the case class (defined in object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715611/why-is-the-error-unable-to-find-encoder-for-type-stored-in-a-dataset-when-enco)
- [perform implicit imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664972/why-is-unable-to-find-encoder-for-type-stored-in-a-dataset-when-creating-a-dat)

However, I don't have any case classes, as I am using `DataFrame` which is equal to `DataSet[Row]`, and also, I've inlined the 2 implicit imports as follows, without any help to get rid of this message.

```
val sparkSession: SparkSession = ???
val sqlContext: SQLContext = ???

import sparkSession.implicits._
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

Note that I've looked at the documentation for [DataSet](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) and [Encoder](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder). The docs says something like the following.

```
Scala

Encoders are generally created automatically through implicits from a 
SparkSession, or can be explicitly created by calling static methods on 
Encoders.

import spark.implicits._

val ds = Seq(1, 2, 3).toDS() // implicitly provided (spark.implicits.newIntEncoder)
```

However, my method doesn't have access to `SparkSession`. Also, when I try that line `import spark.implicits._`, IntelliJ can't even find it. When I say that my DataFrame is a DataSet[Row], I really do mean it.

This question is marked as a possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433419/encoder-error-while-trying-to-map-dataframe-row-to-updated-row), but please let me clarify.

- I have no case class or business object associated.
- I am using .flatMap while the other question is using .map
- implicit imports do not seem to help
- passing a RowEncoder produces a compile-time error e.g. `data.flatMap(row => { ... }, RowEncoder(data.schema))` (too many arguments)

I'm reading the other posts, and let me add, I guess I don't know how this new Spark 2.0 Datasets/DataFrame API is supposed to work. In the Spark shell, the code below works. Note that I [start the spark shell](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) like this `$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0`

```
val schema = StructType(Array(
 StructField("x1", StringType, true),
 StructField("x2", StringType, true),
 StructField("x3", StringType, true),
 StructField("x4", StringType, true),
 StructField("x5", StringType, true)))

val df = sqlContext.read
 .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
 .option("header", "true")
 .schema(schema)
 .load("/Users/jwayne/Downloads/mydata.csv")

df.columns.map(col => {
 df.groupBy(col)
   .count()
   .map(_.getString(0))
   .collect()
   .toList
 })
 .toList
```

However, when I run this as a part of a test unit, I get the same unable to find encoder error. Why does this work in the shell but not in my test units?

In the shell, I typed in `:imports` and `:implicits` and placed those in my scala files/source, but that doesn't help either.

Comment: This is a whole different problem. This is not a duplicate. You get to experience this when we run unit tests. Please unmark it as a duplicate.

Comment: This should not be marked as a duplicate.